# Visualforce Content Type text/csv#filename.csv Renders on One Row

Tags: visualforce, csv

This visualforce page renders a csv but all the data is on one row. Where did I go wrong, how do I get a new row after every apex:repeat?

Note: The code below is on one line to prevent empty header rows when rendering.

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" language="en-US"> Col A","Col B","Col C","Col D","Col E",<apex:repeat value="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Object_Members__r}" var="co"> {!co.Custom_Object__c.Name},{!co.Contact__r.FirstName},{!co.Contact__r.LastName},{!co.Contact__r.Email},{!co.Contact__r.MobilePhone}, </apex:repeat>
```

This code all goes on line:

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" language="en-US"> Col A","Col B","Col C","Col D","Col E",
<apex:repeat value="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Object_Members__r}" var="co"> {!co.Custom_Object__c.Name},{!co.Contact__r.FirstName},{!co.Contact__r.LastName},{!co.Contact__r.Email},{!co.Contact__r.MobilePhone}, 
</apex:repeat></apex:page>
```

This code puts line break where needed (it seems a new line with anything in it adds a new row, "_" in this example.)

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" language="en-US"> Col A","Col B","Col C","Col D","Col E",
_
<apex:repeat value="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Object_Members__r}" var="co"> {!co.Custom_Object__c.Name},{!co.Contact__r.FirstName},{!co.Contact__r.LastName},{!co.Contact__r.Email},{!co.Contact__r.MobilePhone}, 
_
</apex:repeat></apex:page>
```

This example also gives line breaks.

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" language="en-US"> Col A","Col B","Col C","Col D","Col E",
_<apex:repeat value="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Object_Members__r}" var="co"> {!co.Custom_Object__c.Name},{!co.Contact__r.FirstName},{!co.Contact__r.LastName},{!co.Contact__r.Email},{!co.Contact__r.MobilePhone}, 
_</apex:repeat></apex:page>
```

For whatever reason, I need to have text before a return, the visualforce tags themselves do not trigger a new line....what the waffle....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a few newlines:

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" language="en-US"> Col A","Col B","Col C","Col D","Col E",
<apex:repeat value="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Object_Members__r}" var="co"> {!co.Custom_Object__c.Name},{!co.Contact__r.FirstName},{!co.Contact__r.LastName},{!co.Contact__r.Email},{!co.Contact__r.MobilePhone}, 
</apex:repeat></apex:page>
```

apex:repeat tends to be pretty literal when it comes to things like that. Make sure you don't include any space between `</apex:repeat>` and `</apex:page>` if you don't want an extra blank newline at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your help, still no luck, keeps it on one line. Any thoughts? No matter how many lines I break the vf code on it still comes out as one line.

Comment: If I add new lines before the Col A, Col B, etc. it does honor those, but not after. Seems Strange